# Spark job optimization: Is there a way to tune spark job which has too many joins

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Application which does a join on 11 tables. Basically to denormalise a fact table by joining with all dimension tables. Joining happens on Spark. All tables reside in TiDB. Job connects using jdbc connection

Currently, the batch is just 15 min, the number of rows is around 10,000 to 15,000 in fact table. Are there any tuning parameters for joins. Any code that can be optimized. Is there a better way to do this?

Code snippet

```
val factTable = sparkSession.sql("select col1,col2,col3... from fact_table where last_modified_time between lowerBound and higerbound") 

//Get only the rows required from a dimension tables by generating a where clause
//This generates dim1_id=122 OR dim1_id=123 OR dim1_id=124 OR ...

val dim1TableFilter = factTable.map(fact => s"dim1_id = ${fact.dim1_id}").dropDuplicates().reduce(_+" OR "+_)

val dim1Table = sparkSession.sql(s"select col1,col2,col3.... from dim1Table where ${dim1TableFilter}")

val dim2TableFilter = factTable.map(fact => s"dim2_id = ${fact.dim2_id}").dropDuplicates().reduce(_+" OR "+_)
val dim2Table = sparkSession.sql(s"select col1,col2,col3.... from dim2Table where ${dim2TableFilter}")

val dim3TableFilter = factTable.map(fact => s"dim3_id = ${fact.dim3_id}").dropDuplicates().reduce(_+" OR "+_)
val dim3Table = sparkSession.sql(s"select col1,col2,col3.... from dim3Table where ${dim3TableFilter}")
...
....
...... so on 

// Finally join fact tables with dimension tables

val denormalisedTable = factTable.join(dim1Table,Seq("dim1_id"))
    .join(dim2Table,Seq("dim2_id"))
    .join(dim3Table,Seq("dim3_id"))
    .join(dim4Table,Seq("di4_id"))
    .join(dim5Table,Seq("dim5_id"))
    .join(dim6Table,Seq("dim6_id"))
    .join(dim7Table,Seq("dim7_id"))
    .join(dim8Table,Seq("dim8_id"))
    .join(dim9Table,Seq("dim9_id"))
    .join(dim10Table,Seq("dim10_id"))
    .join(dim11Table,Seq("dim11_id"))

// Push the batch to Kafka
 denormalisedTable
      .select(to_json(keyColumns).as("key"), to_json(struct(col1,col2,col3...)).as("value"), current_timestamp().as("timestamp"))
      .selectExpr("CAST(key as STRING)", "CAST(value as STRING)", "CAST(timestamp as LONG)")
      .write
      .format("kafka")
      .options(PropertiesParser.getKafkaConf())
      .option("topic", topicName)
      .save()
```

Comment: See: https://developer.ibm.com/code/2018/04/16/star-schema-enhancements-in-apache-spark/

Answer (score 1):

One of the things you can evaluate is to try and use a map side join. Map side joins can be very good for joins between a large table (fact) with relatively small tables (dimensions) that could then be used to perform a star-schema join. Essentially , this avoids sending large tables across the network for normal hash joins!

Refer : https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-joins-broadcast.html

Comment: Dimension tables can become quite big as well actually.

Comment: Yes true. I have cases where dimension tables are big and can't be handled with map side join. As it is recommended that tables must be small for map side join. But I am curious as to what is considered as small/large in terms of broadcast joins